# Prevent WordPress from interpreting a subfolder?

Tags: 404-error, directory, subdomains

**How do I prevent WordPress from interpreting a subfolder?**

Right now WordPress is installed in the root folder (grassrootsmedia.net/) and I have several other subfolders like (/Clients) that should NOT be styled and interpreted as part of the main WordPress site.

In the past, when you surfed to (grassrootsmedia.net/Clients) the site was not styled nor interpreted by the main WordPress site. Now you get a 404 Error.

Help! How do I hide the subfolders? Or how do I block WordPress from thinking the subfolders are a part of the main site?

Comment: "In the past..."-- What changed? When did this problem start?

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` file look like?  Has it been changed recently?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a directory and all virtual requests to it, extend the regular rules:

```
# WordPress
# Images, Stylesheets etc. don't need a HTML 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.\w{2,4}$
# Existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Do not touch the directory 'clients'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/clients/.*
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```